# twitter analysis hive query

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hiveql

My table is,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE twitter.tweets (id BIGINT,created_at STRING,source STRING,favorited BOOLEAN, retweeted_status STRUCT<text:STRING,user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,retweet_count:INT>,entities STRUCT<urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>, user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
 hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,text STRING,user STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING,friends_count:INT,followers_count:INT,statuses_count:INT,verified:BOOLEAN,utc_offset:INT,time_zone:STRING>,in_reply_to_screen_name STRING) 
PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/twitter';
```

I load the data from HDFS to this table using
`LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/hue/twitter/tweets/2017/03/08/FlumeData.1489005910193' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE tweets PARTITION (datehour)`

I get an error as

> 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED:SemanticException
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:MetaException(message:Invalid
>   partition key & values; keys [datehour, ], values [])'

I don't understand what to write as a value for the partition part

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD DATA INPATH` moves files, nothing more.
If all your records are from the same time (e.g. `23`) then use -
 `...INTO TABLE tweets PARTITION (datehour=23)`.
If not, you'll have to use another technique, e.g. EXTERNAL TABLE.

Comment: Thank you.. before seen your answer I added as PARTITION(datehour=08032017) the date  which  I downloaded the tweets..It worked and hope this is also correct..

Comment: **(1)** `datehour` is a strange name for a column that holds only date and no time. **(2)** since the partition column is of int type, the preceding `0` of `08032017` is meaningless **(3)** I strongly recommend to change the partition definition to another type/format. `date` would be ideal e.g. `PARTITIONED BY (datehour date)` and `INTO TABLE tweets PARTITION (datehour=date '2017-03-08')`. Even if you stay with `int` for some reason use `YYYYMMDD` format e.g. `20170308` so you could use comparisons like `datehour between 20170301 and 20170308`

Comment: If you don't mind could you please provide me a resource( any documents) for twitter data analysis. up to now I have downloaded the data and now i'm stuck with hive table creating.. I have no knowledge of what to do??